# Node.js on Amazon EC2 on Amazon Linux very slow

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I'm an Amazon EC2 and Node.js newbe so I might be in over my head, but I like learning by doing. I've got it working, but the problem is the instance is very slow and I can start Node once or twice, but after that I get this error:

```
Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.697768] ------------[ cut here ]------------

Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.697946] invalid opcode: 0000 [#8] SMP 

Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.697956] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index2/shared_cpu_map

Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.698006] Process node (pid: 27776, ti=d481a000 task=e604be80 task.ti=d481a000)

Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.698006] Stack:

Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.698006] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.698006] Code: 8d 74 26 00 8b 06 c7 46 08 00 00 00 00 e8 d2 52 f7 ff 8b 56 04 83 fa ff 74 a3 8d 46 10 e8 b2 78 00 00 c7 46 04 00 00 00 00 eb 92 <0f> 0b eb fe 90 8d 74 26 00 55 89 e5 83 ec 10 89 7d fc 89 c7 a1 

Message from syslogd@ip-10-56-53-235 at Nov  6 13:41:31 ...
kernel:[171753.698006] EIP: [<c10b9387>] exit_mmap+0x137/0x140 SS:ESP 0069:d481adbc
```

I'm working on a free micro Amazon Linux server. I installed g++, make and openssl using Yum in order to be able to compile Node.js from source downloaded via Git. As I said, this works fine, I can see "hello world" from the public DNS.

Any ideas? Really appreciated!

Comment: And what's the node.js code you're running? That's more likely to be the issue than the server.

Comment: I don't believe it's the code. The code is copied ad verbatim from the Node.js frontpage and works because I can see the write in the browser. Besides, when I run "node" without a script, the same thing happens.

Comment: I didn't solve this one. Moved to an Ubuntu 10.10 instance.

Comment: But I encountered the same problem there. :(

Comment: Are you using the stable or unstable version of node? I've installed it on Ubuntu 10.10 and never encountered this.

Comment: I thought they where all unstable! ;) I tried version 0.6.1.

Comment: 0.6.0 is the latest stable release. http://nodejs.org/#download

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.
Question here is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117446/node-js-older-than-0-4-12-dont-work-correctly-on-aws-ec2-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same problem and found this thread:

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2271

After following the instructions in the "Known Issues" section here:

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/latest-release-notes/

I'm running v0.6.6 on a micro instance without issues.

Answer (score 0):

install v0.4.12, it's work fine on AWS EC2