# Node.js older than 0.4.12 don't work correctly on AWS EC2. Why?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, centos

I can't install node.js v0.6.1 on AWS EC2 (Ubuntu or CentOs - never mind).
After installation I type node, and processor loads to 100%.

But v0.4.12 works fine.

May be only I have this problem? Sorry then.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027506/node-js-on-amazon-ec2-on-amazon-linux-very-slow

Comment: Are you in a micro instance? Remember there is no swap space setup on EC2 by default, and in micro your memory is real small. Check dmesg to see if your getting kernel errors on memory.

Comment: Ed H., yes, I'm using micro. But why 0.4.12 works well? I'm typing only node, and CPU usage is 99% by node. WTF?

Comment: I don't much about why Node.js would do that specifically. I can tell you google sparsehash tests crash on micro, as well as other stuff. If for some reason your hitting the roof on memory, then malloc()s are failing and there is no telling what that does to Node.js.

Comment: Ed H., may be... why 0.6.x do this? I didn't try linux 64bit

Comment: No idea. My with problems with micro were on 64-bit ubuntu and centos. Swap space solved my issues.

Comment: Do you just create swap and 0.6.x starts work fine? (I'm asking about AWS EC2)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the specifics are too old to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I had successfully install 0.6.x in ubuntu 11.04, Download nodejs from http://nodejs.org/

Do not install from sudo apt-get install node. This will install radio package. this radio package requires axports to be active, which is not linked with nodejs

After installing then set the environment variables echo PATH=$PTATH:/home/user/pathtonode/

Comment: are you hosting on AWS? On localhost and dedicated server everything is ok. Of course I'm installing node from sources

Answer (score 0):

I had the same / similar problem.

on standard 32-bit linux AMI with node v0.6, and redis package, if i opened node command line:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var r = redis.createClient();
r.quit();
```

the cpu would go to 100%.

I went to a ubuntu image, this time if I installed node v0.6, just running npm caused cpu to go to 100%.

What solved both situations was installing node v0.4.12.

Comment: Yeah! But this is don't solve problem, because v0.4.12 is to old. 0.6x will be better in prod. I'm really interested WHY it's happening?