# Installing NPM on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, npm

Working on Ec2 on AWS.

I have installed Node.js and it works fine.

But the problem arises when trying to install npm.

I am using the following command to install it:

```
sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

But the install seems to freeze...
I get "fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.106.tgz" at the prompt and it stays on like this.

Have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Sometimes the registry is down. Check out this page: http://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html

Comment: try node.js v. 0.4.12

similar problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117446/node-js-older-than-0-4-12-dont-work-correctly-on-aws-ec2-why

Comment: Make sure that HTTPS (port 443) is allowed in the outbound security group of the instance

Comment: @dade Can you update this question and mark the correct answer as of today? That would be to use the NVM, as Derek pointed out in comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/44509677/3117194

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Follow this [AWS Tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html) that uses [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).**

Node Version Manager (NVM) lets you install multiple versions of Node.js and switch between them.

---

**Here are the steps:**

Install NVM

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
```

Activate NVM

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Install Node (choose version)

```
nvm install 15.0.0
```

Confirm Successful Installation

```
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
```

Comment: using this method; `node` and `npm` are installed only when I access them, if I used something like `pm2` to deploy my app; I get `npm: command not found`, why can this happen?

Comment: You can install npm using nvm. `nvm install-latest-npm`

Answer (score 126):

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```

Comment: The question neither stats the OS being run nor, if CentOS/RHEL, which version, nor if the EPEL repo is installed.  NodeJS and NPM are not in the RHEL5 EPEL repo, for example.

Comment: this was auto flagged due to length, pleas add a little explanation.

Comment: this version no longer looks to be the current stable version of node.js, maybe something is up with the mirror?

Comment: @ChinaPaul Same here. i get a very old version, and when I try to update npm, then, it is broken.

Comment: best to run `npm install npm -g` after installing this way to update to latest version of `npm`

Comment: For me, this installed Node 0.X, which is unacceptable. I ended up building nodejs from source, which took 20 minutes.

Comment: $ sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found

Below works: see my comment

Comment: `Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found`

Answer (score 43):

To install NodeJS 6.x execute the following commands:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
yum install nodejs --enablerepo=nodesource
```

**Update**

You can install NodeJS 7 and 8 in the same way. Just specify the version you need instead of 6 in the command above.

**Update**

To update to NodeJS 16 (or any other version) do the following:

```
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource-el*
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
yum install nodejs --enablerepo=nodesource
```

Comment: how do i uninstall 6 and install 7? if i already install 6 this way?

Comment: @PK. Updated the answer

Comment: This did not work for me, I get the message `Package 2:nodejs-6.16.0-1nodesource.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do` and when I check the version it's still `v6.16.0` . - how do I upgrade to 10?

Comment: This just saved me so much headache. I tried all possible and was getting the error "npm command not found" till i did tis.

Comment: rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource-el*
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo yum install nodejs --enablerepo=nodesource -y

Answer (score 11):

Simplest way to install npm/nodejs on Amazon Linux 2 ec2 isntance:

1. First install epel repo using amazon-linux-extras command as below:

> `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel`

2. Now install npm and nodejs as below:

> `sudo yum install nodejs npm`

3. you can verify the version of node and npm as below:

> `node -v`
>
> `npm -v`

PS. I've tested this on Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) ec2 instance.

Comment: thank you!!! this answer should be on top 2021/10

Comment: dosent work for me.. There are a few missing dependencies

Comment: sudo yum install nodejs npm --skip-broken -> worked for me

Comment: Error: Package: 1:nodejs-16.18.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libuv >= 1:1.43.0
           Available: 1:libuv-1.23.2-1.amzn2.0.2.i686 (amzn2-core)

Comment: this is the only one worked for me, if you get libuv error run `yum remove libuv -y` then `  yum install libuv --disableplugin=priorities`

Answer (score 9):

This guide worked perfectly: https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-amazon-linux/

1. Make sure you have make

`# sudo yum install -y gcc-c++ make`

2. Install source

`# curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -`

3. Install node

`# sudo yum install -y nodejs`

Note - you'll have to run `sudo npm install` to get the installs to work.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly

sudo yum install make

You can run this to get zip of desired version of node

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.10.0/node-v8.10.0.tar.gz
```

Then you can unzip it like this

```
tar -xvf node-v8.10.0.tar.gz
```

then go in to the extracted directory and install node like this

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: What does ./configure do? from inside the extracted directory I get the error `./configure: No such file or directory`   I just downloaded the linux binary `https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz` to my mac to peek around, and there is no file ./configure in the unzipped directory

Comment: @AgentZebra : cd node-v10.15.1-linux-x64 then ./configure && make && sudo make install. this will build and install the node

Answer (score 1):

I found his tutorial that has been very usefull to me: The last chapter explains how to install node and npm compiling it.

http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/#installNode

Answer (score 1):

Get the `http://npmjs.org/install.sh` file on your system first and then execute it directly instead of piping with curl.

- Use `chmod +x install.sh` to make it executable
- Then run `./install.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I did it manually.  Why mess with installers that break or don't put things where I want them?  Such were the problems encountered while installing *node.js" on Amazon Web Services, that a manual install was the easy way to get the result I wanted.

I want a GLOBAL install of `node` and `npm` on AWS.  By that I mean install should be put in a place like `/usr/bin`, so that all users have access.  Surprisingly, AWS apparently doesn't give support to that idea.  AWS encourages using `nvm`, *node version manager*, but that seems to always install in a user directory, and not a system level directory.  After being frustrated when the "rpm" solutions (mentioned elsewhere) failed, I finally decided to just do the installation manually.

In a browser, go to nodejs.org download page:

```
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

Find a link that says:

```
All download options
```

Click through that; it goes to an index page with a URL like:

```
https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/
```

There I looked for the name that had "linux" and "x86" in the name.
I wrote this down, or select-and-copied, to get the correct spelling.
In my case it was:

```
node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Putting the two parts together, I got the following URL:

```
https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

So that's what is to be downloaded using `curl`.

I have a "temp" directory conveniently located in my home dir.

```
cd ~/temp
```

The download was accomplished with "curl".  Note that the `-o` option was used to give the *output* file the name of my choosing.  Of course, I chose to give it the same name as the web site file.

```
curl -o node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz  https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Untar the downloaded file.

```
tar xf node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Conveniently, it creates its own directory.  Go there.

```
cd node-v14.16.1-linux-x64 || exit 1;
```

Observe that the delivery consists of a relatively small number of files and directories (since *node_modules* is dealt with as a unit).

In my case, I had an old and bad implementation still installed, so the following commands were used to move aside any junk that might happen to be in the way.  Some commands errored out because the old junk didn't exist.  That's ok, error while moving to `-OLD` just means there is nothing to move; which is good.

Note: I put all these `mv` (move) commands into a script file, made it executable, and ran it as `sudo`.  The alternative is to run each line individually as `sudo`.

```
mv /usr/bin/node    /usr/bin/node-OLD
mv /usr/bin/npm             /usr/bin/npm-OLD
mv /usr/bin/npx             /usr/bin/npx-OLD
mv /usr/include/node                /usr/include/node-OLD
mv /usr/lib/node_modules    /usr/lib/node_modules-OLD
mv /usr/share/doc/node                      /usr/share/doc/node-OLD
mv /usr/share/man/man1/node.1               /usr/share/man/man1/node.1-OLD
mv /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp             /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp-OLD
```

An here is the actual install.  Remember, this is occurring in the untarred directory, in my case *node-v14.16.1-linux-x64*.

```
mv bin/node         /usr/bin
mv bin/npm          /usr/bin
mv bin/npx          /usr/bin
mv include/node             /usr/include
mv lib/node_modules         /usr/lib
mv share/doc/node           /usr/share/doc
mv share/man/man1/node.1            /usr/share/man/man1
mv share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp          /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/
```

That's it, all finished.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
sudo apt install npm
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest version 18 has dependency I think..

```
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

Finally I got solution by running by running following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
nvm install 16.15.1
```

v16.15.1 node version and npm v v16.15.1 is installed.
For same make sure nvm is installed in your machine.

Comment: Out of all the answers this currently works. Others seem to have issues with dependencies .

Answer (score -3):

Edit as my answer wasn't pertinent anymore:

Try:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -

yum -y install nodejs
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#enterprise-linux-and-fedora-core

Comment: FYI, `nodejs.tchol.org` link is now broken (for anyone coming here a year later).

Comment: Out of date, no longer listed on the page given.