# Upgrading node on Linux EC2 - how to install after unzipping the gz file?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

Linux EC2 currently running Node version v6.16.0. I've upzipped the gz file for version 10 (https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.1/node-v10.15.1-linux-x64.tar.gz).

To get it to install / upgrade, another post suggested running `./configure && make && sudo make install`
  - however there's no configure file in the unzipped directory.

What commands do I run to get it to upgrade?

Comment: What operating system specifically is the EC2 server running? Why are you not using the OS package manager like `yum` or `apt-get` to install Node?

Comment: Linux. I installed an earlier version by mistake with yum - now trying to upgrade it. I was following instructions in this SO `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205369/installing-npm-on-aws-ec2` - maybe I should delete, and then just reinstall the updated version, but I'd still like to know how to upgrade from the unzipped tarball

Comment: "Linux" isn't exactly specific. Ubuntu, CentOS, Amazon Linux...?

Comment: Amazon Linux. Is there a difference in the command to install depending on the Linux version?

Comment: Yes the available libraries, and the package manager you would use, would be different depending on exact Linux distribution you are using.