# `npm install` command is getting stuck while running docker build on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Trying to build and run the docker image on ec2 instance for creating pipeline. But everytime the code is getting stuck on npm install to bypass the issue tried putting the command on a script and tried executing but its failing.

Can anyone provide the solution.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /App
COPY package*.json /tmp/
COPY . .
CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]
COPY bash.sh /tmp/
RUN bash /tmp/bash.sh
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

**bash.sh**

```
npm install
```

**Output**

```
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon   7.06MB
Step 1/9 : FROM node
 ---> 8d6c41e6504f
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /App
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dc60237f627c
Step 3/9 : COPY package*.json /tmp/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bbd013f7bc5e
Step 4/9 : COPY . .
 ---> e28beed562c8
Step 5/9 : CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]
 ---> Running in 9cb0e7128c36
Removing intermediate container 9cb0e7128c36
 ---> 0a59fdf80b76
Step 6/9 : COPY bash.sh /tmp/
 ---> a4bf4c096fb3
Step 7/9 : RUN bash /tmp/bash.sh
 ---> Running in 44a816da40ae
```

Comment: It might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205369/installing-npm-on-aws-ec2

Comment: what inside `/tmp/bash.sh`?

Comment: `npm install` is is inside bash.sh

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include that script?  Can you push the image to a registry and pull it on the EC2 instance, without rebuilding it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Finally fixed the issue by creating a script file and running the script inside the Dockerfile.**

You can also refer to this ***[AWS Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html#setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance-procedure)***

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /App

COPY package.json .

COPY package-lock.json .

COPY . .

COPY bash.sh /tmp/

RUN bash /tmp/bash.sh

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

> bash.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 15.0.0
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
```

I hope this is would be working fine for the issue.

Comment: The question is already using a script file, and the Dockerfile looks fairly similar to what's in this answer.

Comment: The docker file is similar as the question but the script file is changed previously inside the script it was ```npm install``` but now the script is changed and for that reason the issue is getting fixed.